# ASP.NET Core MVC can't access model field using ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get the "Name" field in the "Blog" model, i.e.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This is the relevant code in the index method of the controller

```
var posts = await _context.Posts
                          .Where(p => p.BlogId == id && p.ReadyStatus == ReadyStatus.ProductionReady)
                          .Include(p => p.Blog)
                          .OrderByDescending(b => b.Created)
                          .ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize);
ViewData["BlogName"] = Blog.Name;
```

But the last line, the at `Blog.Name`, I get this error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property for "Blog.Name"

Comment: Could you show the entire method AND the call to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to find ONE Blog, with a specific page of its latest production ready posts.

I'd invert the approach to this, because this will still find the blog even if there are no posts at that page:

```cs
Blog? blog = await _context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => blog.Id == id)
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts
        .Where(post => post.ReadyStatus == ReadyStatus.ProductionReady)
        .OrderByDescending(post => post.Created)
        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
    )
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
if (blog == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("The blog was not found.", nameof(id));
}
ViewData["BlogName"] = blog.Name;
```

Then you can access the page list of `Posts` inside the found `Blog` like this: `blog.Posts`. It will contain a `List<Post>` of production ready blog posts for the given page, ordered descendingly by creation time.

As you've noted in the comments, your ViewModel requires a custom type of list `X.PagedList.IPagedList`.
You can try and create it manually from the `blog.Posts`, `pageSize` and `pageNumber`.

If you want to keep your approach:

```cs
var blogPosts = await _context.Posts
    .Where(p => p.BlogId == id && p.ReadyStatus == ReadyStatus.ProductionReady)
    .Include(p => p.Blog)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Created)
    .ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize);
if (blogPosts.Count < 1) 
{
    // here you react when there are no blog posts found for given id and page parameters.
}
ViewData["BlogName"] = blogPosts[0].Blog.Name;
```

Comment: I basically want to show the name of the blog at the top of the index view with -- Posts for @ViewData["BlogName"]. So I'd like that if there are no posts it goes to the index view which would be blank if there are no posts in that blog. There the user can access the create button

Comment: @David could you please try the suggested solutions and see if they fix your issue?

Comment: The first solution throws this error 
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'DevBlog5.Models.Blog', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'X.PagedList.IPagedList`1[DevBlog5.Models.Post]'.

The second solution works. I have been working on the error handling for that one. I'm looking into having a dialog box that says there are no posts would you like to create one, if no return to blog index, if yes go to create view.

Comment: @David I'm glad I helped you. Please mark the answer as correct and upvote it, as a thank you for my effort. I would not like to solve your problem for you, the point of this site is to answer questions and teach people, not do their work for them. What you want to do requires a lot of effort not related to this question, but is easy if you try yourself and try to learn how razor works. If you have any other concrete question/problem you can create a new question about it.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer and I will do as you ask. I apologize, I didn't mean to imply that I wanted you to do the work for me. I mentioned the error handling just for the sake of conversation. I didn't expect you to do that for me. Your second solution works so thank you for that. The first solution doesn't. I will look into it further.  Kind Regards.

Comment: Now that you've edited the comment I understand what you wanted to say. I initially understood you asked me if I wanted to create that for you. It's all good, no need to apologize :). I've edited the answer to include an example for the first solution on how you can access the paged list of `Posts` found for the blog inside the returned `blog` object. Hope that helps